# Replace tridimensional values with numpy with 0 in a colored image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have the following image:

[image]

I would like to replace the yellow background with black. I don't know the exact values of the yellow in RGB, but I would like to replace this yellow with black (RGB 0,0,0). With numpy.where, I would like to know if it is possible to fill positions with RGB different from [255,255,255] with [0,0,0], but I don't know how to do a numpy.where considering three dimensions.

Any way of doing that in Python?

Comment: Yes it does! thank you!

Comment: opencv `inRange` -> mask -> numpy indexing with mask or opencv's own methods